# Tensorflow: How to randomly crop input images and labels in the same way?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to take random crops from an image. Just like it's done in Caffe for the sake of data augmentation.

I know that tensorflow already has a function

```
    img = tf.random_crop(img, [h, w, 3])
    label = tf.random_crop(label, [h, w, 1])
```

But I'm not sure whether it takes it takes the same crop for image and label. Also this function cannot automatically 0-pad images with one or two dimensions smaller than the crop size [h,w].

That again is done by

```
    img = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(img, h, w)
    label = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(label, h, w)
```

But it takes only center crops not random crops.

Edit:
Here is some code how the padding could be done:

```
# Cropping dimensions (crops of 700 x 800)
crp_h = tf.constant(700)
crp_w = tf.constant(800)

shape = tf.shape(img)
img_h = shape[0]
img_w = shape[1]    
img = tf.cond(img_h < crp_h, lambda: tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box(img, 0, 0, crp_h, img_w), lambda: img)
# Update image dimensions
shape = tf.shape(img)
img_h = shape[0]
img = tf.cond(img_w < crp_w, lambda: tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box(img, 0, 0, img_h, crp_w), lambda: img)
# Update image dimensions
shape = tf.shape(img)
img_w = shape[1]
```

Unfortunately one cannot use the python `if` conditional here so one has to go with the ugly `tf.cond(...)` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest combining the image with the labels and randomly cropping them together:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def random_crop_and_pad_image_and_labels(image, labels, size):
  """Randomly crops `image` together with `labels`.

  Args:
    image: A Tensor with shape [D_1, ..., D_K, N]
    labels: A Tensor with shape [D_1, ..., D_K, M]
    size: A Tensor with shape [K] indicating the crop size.
  Returns:
    A tuple of (cropped_image, cropped_label).
  """
  combined = tf.concat([image, labels], axis=2)
  image_shape = tf.shape(image)
  combined_pad = tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box(
      combined, 0, 0,
      tf.maximum(size[0], image_shape[0]),
      tf.maximum(size[1], image_shape[1]))
  last_label_dim = tf.shape(labels)[-1]
  last_image_dim = tf.shape(image)[-1]
  combined_crop = tf.random_crop(
      combined_pad,
      size=tf.concat([size, [last_label_dim + last_image_dim]],
                     axis=0))
  return (combined_crop[:, :, :last_image_dim],
          combined_crop[:, :, last_image_dim:])
```

As an example:

```
cropped_image, cropped_labels = random_crop_and_pad_image_and_labels(
    image=tf.reshape(tf.range(4*4*3), [4, 4, 3]),
    labels=tf.reshape(tf.range(4*4), [4, 4, 1]),
    size=[2, 2])

with tf.Session() as session:
  print(session.run([cropped_image, cropped_labels]))
```

Prints something like:

```
[array([[[30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]],

       [[42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47]]], dtype=int32), array([[[10],
        [11]],

       [[14],
        [15]]], dtype=int32)]
```

And a second example with an under-sized image:

```
cropped_image, cropped_labels = random_crop_and_pad_image_and_labels(
    image=tf.reshape(tf.range(4*1*3), [4, 1, 3]),
    labels=tf.reshape(tf.range(4*1), [4, 1, 1]),
    size=[2, 2])

with tf.Session() as session:
  print(session.run([cropped_image, cropped_labels]))
```

Prints:

```
[array([[[3, 4, 5],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[6, 7, 8],
        [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=int32), array([[[1],
        [0]],

       [[2],
        [0]]], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It turns out the part with the padding is also a bit evolved. I assume one can use the function `tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box(...)` but unfortunately one cannot use the pyhton `if` for the conditional. I added the pseudo code for that to my question. I'm working on that but for any help I would be grateful

Comment: I guess I found it (see my Edit to the question)

Comment: I've added a padding step

Comment: Turns out that tensorflow throws an error like this because it cannot infer the 3rd dimension of image and label at graph compile time (static shape). This causes the function tf.train.batch(...) to fail. I'll try to fix it and report it here

Comment: That's always going to be 3 and 1 respectively, right? You could use `image.set_shape((None, None, 3))` and `labels.set_shape((None, None, 1))` if so.

Comment: @AllenLavoie couldn't consistent cropping for multiple tensors be achieved simply by setting the same `seed` argument for all the random crops? That is, something like this: `images = tf.random_crop(images, size, seed=1); labels = tf.random_crop(labels, size, seed=1)`

Comment: @RohanSaxena I wouldn't recommend it. Setting the op-level seed is one part, but [there's also a tricky graph-level seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) and the state stored in the kernel to avoid producing exactly the same crop each `Session.run` call.

Comment: @AllenLavoie I knew about the graph-level seed, but not about the state stored in the kernel. Could you please point me to someplace that elaborates on how that works?

Comment: The hope is to switch to [stateless random ops which take the current seed as input and then output a new mutated seed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/stateless_random_ops.cc#L67). But the current implementations [mutate a value in the kernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9a0d466dc43f14e6b2b58f814c05365aaba23b37/tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op.cc#L213) when run. I think the graph seed interaction is more problematic in this case, since it relies on the number of previously created ops.

Comment: @AllenLavoie, what about if we have a batch of images and labels and we want to return a batch of crop

Comment: Should `pad_to_bounding_box()` be called after `random_crop()` to ensure the output shape is the same as the input?